# Angular Show Child Component When clicking on parent Component

Tags: angular

When I click on dashboard I want to show a child component in the view. I have dashboard component and Home, Pets, bookings all are child components. When a user logged in and redirect to dashboard i want to show the home component but URL will remain only dashboard. Also when i want to set routerlinkactive. Please find my code below.

Routing Module :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: DashboardHomeComponent },
      { path: 'booking', component: DashboardBookingComponent },
      { path: 'pets', component: DashboardPetsComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: DashboardProfileComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Sidebar Component :

```
<div class="dashboard-left-outer">
    <div class="dashboard-menu">
        <ul>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['dashboard']"><p>dashboard</p></a></li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['pets']"><p>pets</p></a></li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['booking']"></i><p>booking</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: booking (and pets) are child routes of the dashboard route. So the routerLink should be `'/dashboard/booking'`, not `'booking'`.

Comment: How can i set the url to dashboard but it will load home component.

Comment: add an empty child route on dashboard that redirects to home. Navigating to /dashboard will automatically redirect to /dashboard/home and thus display the home component.

Comment: children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      { path: 'home', component: DashboardHomeComponent },
      { path: 'booking', component: DashboardBookingComponent },
      { path: 'pets', component: DashboardPetsComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: DashboardProfileComponent }
    ]

Comment: still the url is http://localhost:4200/dashboard/home.   How can i set to only dashboard

Comment: the route that redirect should have an **empty** path. So that when you navigate to /dashboard, this route is selected, and redirects to /dashboard/home. The URL of the page will still be /dashboard/home, but /dashboard will redirect to it.

Comment: Yes now the URL worked and also the the left panel links. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to control navigation if you want to stay on site.com/dashboard and see the child page

```js
//on init
this.localStoragePage = getPageFromLocalStorage() || 'home'

//on page link click you should update the local storage
```

```html
//in dashboard page
<homeComponent *ngIf="this.localStoragePage ='home'" >
<petsComponent *ngIf="this.localStoragePage ='pets'" >
```

Or if you don't mind to change the URL you can redirect from dashboard page to home page like @JB Nizet suggested
Put this in your dashboard component:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home'])
```